# Extracting a random sublist from a list in Python

Tags: python, random, sublist

I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
{'APPLE_PROVIDERS' : ["some", "provider","can","be", "null"],
  ....
}
```

What i want to do is get a random sublist from the list (which is a value) of a key. Not just one element, but a totally random sublist. Here is what I tried:

```
a_list = a_dict.get('APPLE_PROVIDERS', "")
for item in a_list[randrange(0,len(a_list)) : randrange(0,len(a_list))]:
  ...do something..
```

This thing has two problems :

1. If the list is empty, or if the dict lookup fails, the program fails since randrange has (0,0) as arguments, which results in an error
2. Many times both randrange() calls generate the same number, especially when the list is small. This returns an empty list. For example a_list[5:5]

So what is the best way to get a random sublist with above cases handled ? Also, I do not care about the ordering. Anything works. I just want a totally random sublist of either 0,1... till len(a_list) elements each time the for loop starts.

If the list can be changed in some other data structure which can hold similar elements, that works for me too.

Comment: Just to be clear: You want a randomly chosen sequence of contiguous elements from the original list?

Comment: In your random sublist, can there be repeated elements? What length should your random sublist be?

Answer (score 35):

Sample it.

```
>>> random.sample(["some", "provider", "can", "be", "null"], 3)
['some', 'can', 'provider']
>>> random.sample(["some", "provider", "can", "be", "null"], 3)
['can', 'null', 'provider']
>>> random.sample(["some", "provider", "can", "be", "null"], 3)
['null', 'some', 'provider']
```

Comment: I want a sublist of either 0,1,2,3..len-1 elements and not just a specific number..

Comment: Did you try replacing the number with something else?

Comment: @user775093, do you require a "fair" distribution?

Comment: Fair is not necessary.. I got what Ignacio was hinting at i think. In the loop before doing a sample, il randomly change the second argument, bound to the length of the list. But will that give a sublist which is not in sequence ? Or do i need to do a shuffle each time ? Eg. i would like to have a sublist in reverse order..

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> left = randint(0, len(L))
>>> right = randint(left, len(L))
>>> L[left:right]
['null']
```

if you don't want the possiblity of empty lists

```
>>> left = randint(0, len(L) - 1)
>>> right = randint(left + 1, len(L))
```

Comment: But this will not be in random. You will always get a sublist that is in the same sequence as the original list. If I understand the question correctly, you should also be able to get a list that is not in sequence.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, the sample code given is attempting to get a slice. The problem seems to be that the slice is often empty (because the ends of the slice are reversed)

Answer (score 2):

[Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910062/1473772) is great. If you want to minimally modify your code, you can do this:

```
a_list = a_dict.get('APPLE_PROVIDERS', "")
if len(a_list) > 1:
    index1 = randrange(0,len(a_list)-1)
    index2 = randrange(index1+1,len(a_list))
    for item in a_list[index1:index2]:
        pass #do stuff
```

I do two things here: 1) I check to see if a_list has more than one element, and 2) I generate indices using randrange, but in such a way that the second is guaranteed to be greater than the first.

Comment: `if len(a_list)` can simply be `if a_list` (saves you a `len()` call). I'd also suggest making this a generator function (replace `pass` with `yield item`).

Comment: `if a_list` is equivalent to `if len(a_list) > 0`, which is not the same. Whether `pass` should be `yield` depends on what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @elendia-starman: Ah, sorry, I mentally stepped over the `> 1`. And the generator is just more pythonic, especially given the use case in from the question.

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming that you want an empty list returned if you get an empty list, here's an example solution:

```
from random import shuffle

def get_random_sublist(the_dict, key, number):
    l = the_dict.get(key, [])
    shuffle(l)
    return l[:number]
```

So, I'd use `random.shuffle`. This allows me to avoid the issue of asking for a sublist that's larger than the actual list that we get.

```
>>> DICT = {'a' : "1 2 3 4 5".split(), 'b': [], 'c': [1]}
>>> get_random_sublist(DICT, 'a', 3)
['4', '1', '2']
>>> get_random_sublist(DICT, 'b', 10)
[]
```